# Change background color of entire row when tabbed?

Tags: html-table, focus, background-color

I have a simple table with two columns and five rows. I want it to be more keyboard accessible.

Left column is just text, right column are buttons that fill when focused/hovered.

Is there a way to change background color of entire row when tabbed (focused) and fill the button background color at the same time?

Comment: Code code code! Where is your Code??

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Added for `focus`

Assuming you have a table like this:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr class="hoverable-row">
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hoverable-row">>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hoverable-row">>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

then in css

```
.hoverable-row:hover, :focus { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: So that CSS works fine when hovering, but I need it to apply when accessed by the keyboard? I will edit main question, sorry for not asking in the best way :D